# ドット演算子とアロー演算子の違いについて

Tags: c, array, ポインタ

[参考記事](https://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19474)では以下のように違いについて書かれていましたが、理解できないため、ベクトルのノルムを求めるリストの疑似コードにおいてどのように書かれるのか知りたいです。

> ドット演算子は構造体やクラスに対してhoge.fugaのように使い、メンバにアクセスします。
>   アロー演算子は構造体やクラスを指すポインタに対してphoge->fugaのように使い、メンバにアクセスします。
>   phoge->fugaと(*phoge).fugaは同じ意味です。

該当擬似コード
構造体（ドット演算子の時）

```
strut cell{
  int index;
  double value;
  struct cell* next;
}
```

ドット演算子

```
norm <- 0
next_address <- v
while next_address != NULL do
    current_cell <- *(next_address)
    norm <- (ベクトルの要素を2乗したものを足していくと考えられるが、擬似コードでどのようにかいたらいいかわからない）
    next_address <- (現在のセルのポインタが指すインデックスだと考えられるが、似コードでどのようにかいたらいいかわからない)
return sqrt(norm)
```

アロー演算子（引用元は[過去質問のご回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55329/%E3%83%99%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%83%8E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/55331#55331)）

```
sum <- 0.0
while v != NULL do
    sum <- sum + v->value * v->value
    v <- v->next
return sqrt(sum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> phoge->fugaと(*phoge).fugaは同じ意味です。

この通りです。

たとえば質問文中にある疑似コードを補完して次のように書いたとします。

```
while next_address != NULL do
    current_cell <- *next_address
    norm <- norm + current_cell.value * current_cell.value
    next_address <- current_cell.next
```

ここで、変数 `next_address` は `struct cell` 型の構造体を指すポインタで、変数 `current_cell` は `struct cell` 型の構造体そのものです。この上で `current_cell` のメンバー `value` を参照する際は、ドット演算子を使って `current_cell.value` と書きます。

ところでこの疑似コードを次のように書くこともできます。

```
while next_address != NULL do
    norm <- norm + (*next_address).value * (*next_address).value
    next_address <- (*next_address).next
```

こうするといちいち `current_cell` を定義しなくてよくなります。一方でいちいち `(*next_address)` と書かないといけないのは面倒です。こういうときアロー演算子を使って簡単に書けます。

```
while next_address != NULL do
    norm <- norm + next_address->value * next_address->value
    next_address <- next_address->next
```

このように、アロー演算子は「ポインタの指している先の構造体のメンバー」を参照できる演算子です。この意味で

> phoge->fugaと(*phoge).fugaは同じ意味です。

ということです。

<sup>※なお、`current_cell` を消したことでデータのコピーが1回分無くなるというメリットがあります。</sup>

Comment: 大変わかりやすいご説明をありがとうございます。
オーダー記法で計算量を考えると、n次元のベクトルが全て0以外だった時にn回normが計算されるのでO(n)という理解で合っていますか。
計算量をオーダ記法で書くとドット演算子・アロー演算子のアルゴリズム共に同じO(n)でしょうか。

Comment: @NPP 元の質問内容と離れてしまっているので、新しく質問として立てて頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: かしこまりました。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55351/%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E5%AD%90%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E5%AD%90%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%83%99%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%83%8E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E9%87%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6?noredirect=1#comment59370_55351　で質問させていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

`p->mem` は `(*p).mem` と同義です。って既に自分で書かれていますよね。

擬似コードでどう書けばよい？　ってことだとしょせん擬似コードですから自分（や第三者）にわかるように書けばそれでいいんです。コンパイラに通すわけでもなし。

擬似コードを実際に [c](/questions/tagged/c) コンパイラに通すのであれば [c](/questions/tagged/c) の文法に合うように書かざるを得ませんし、そのときはドットとアローは使い分けます。