# Maximum Sum Sublistというプログラミング問題をO(n^2)とO(n^3)で解くアルゴリズムのちがいについて

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

[Maximum Sum Sublist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-maximum-sum-sublist/)という
配列で複数の整数が与えられた時に、和が最も大きくなる範囲とその和を求める
プログラミング問題があります。

この問題は時間計算量O(n^2)とO(n^3)で解くアルゴリズムがあるのですが
同じアルゴリズムでも解釈によってO(n^2)にもO(n^3)にもなるとのことで
明確にO(n^2)とO(n^3)と区別できるプログラムもしくはアルゴリズムをそれぞれ探しています。

以下のコードは時間計算量O(n^2)と考えていますが、A[i:j+1]がO(j − i)回かかるので、O(n^3)と[他の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374508/is-there-any-algorithm-whose-time-complexity-is-on3-for-maximum-sum-sublist?noredirect=1)で説明されました。

```
def solution(A):
    start = None
    end = None
    max_total = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            tmp = sum(A[i:j+1])
            if max_total < tmp:
                max_total = tmp
                start = i
                end = j

    return max_total, start, end


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [18, -10, 30, 23, -26]
    ans = solution(A)
    print(ans)
```

Maximum Sum Sublistを解く時に
明確にO(n^2)とO(n^3)と区別できるプログラムもしくはアルゴリズムが知りたいです。

Comment: 「同じアルゴリズムでも解釈によってO(n^2)にもO(n^3)にもなる」ということはないと思います．そこに誤解があって質問全体が曖昧になっていると感じます．疑問についてもう少し詳しく説明できますか？

Comment: `sum(A[i:j+1])`は`O(n)`なんで、掲載のコードは`O(n^3)`ですね。`n`が増加した時に計算量が増える操作を「関数を呼んだ回数は1だから計算量コストも1」なんてやってると、アルゴリズムの一部を別関数にしただけで計算量が変わってしまうことになります。

Comment: リンク先の回答は、数値のリストのリスト (入れ子のリスト) が与えられたときに、最も合計が大きい内側のリストを求めるアルゴリズムなんですが、リンクの間違いでしょうか。

Comment: @Yosh コメントいただきましてありがとうございます。１つのアルゴリズムが複数の計算量と捉えられることはないと思いますが、O(n^2)とO(n^3)のコードを示していただけたらこの点曖昧さが解消されて明白になるのではないかと思い、質問させていただきました。

Comment: 「同じアルゴリズムでも解釈によってO(n^2)にもO(n^3)にもなるとのこと」と言うのをどこで見られたのか、お教え願えませんか?

Comment: @OOPer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374508/is-there-any-algorithm-whose-time-complexity-is-on3-for-maximum-sum-sublist?noredirect=1 と https://teratail.com/questions/192033 です

Comment: 1つ目のリンクの質問中のコード、2つ目のリンクの回答中のコードは解釈によらずO(n^3)ですね…。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントに書かせていただきましたが、ご質問中のコードは解釈の余地も何もなく明確に`O(n^3)`なので、あなたが見つけなければいけないのは、明確に`O(n^2)`のコード、と言うことになります。

(「`sum`の呼び出し回数」と言うことなら質問のコードは`O(n^2)`ですが、そんなものはアルゴリズムを議論する場合の計算量とは言いません。)

コメントの2個目のリンク中の質問側のコードを修正したものですが。これなら`O(n^2)`になります。

```
def solution(A):
    start = None
    end = None
    max_total = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        tmp = 0
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            tmp += A[j]
            if max_total < tmp:
                max_total = tmp
                start = i
                end = j

    return max_total, start, end

A = [18, -10, 30, 23, -26, 37, 48, -19, -13, 31]
ans = solution(A)
print(ans) #->(120, 0, 6)
```

肝心なところは、`for j`で回している内側ループ内には、`n`に応じて計算量が増えるような操作が入っていないことです。(計算量のことも考えずに「合計を求めるには`sum`を使わないとダサい」なんて短絡的な回答もあったようですが、ちゃんと1個ずつ足していかないと、`for j`のループが`O(n)`になりません。)

ネット上を探せば`O(n * log n)`や`O(n)`の回答が見つかります。既にお気づきだろうとは思いますが。

---

## 【ざっくりと時間計算量の見積もり方】

まず大前提は、アルゴリズムを議論するときのBig-Oは、特に断らない限り時間計算量を表していると言うことです。

つまり、

### 基準量`n`の増減に対して、計算時間がどう増減するかを表す指標

であると言うことです。決して「見えている部分のループの回数」ではありません。

`n`を増やしていったら処理時間がどんどん増えていくのに、見かけのループがないから`O(1)`なんて指標を出されても困りますよね?

例えばこんな処理:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A.sort()
    #... ソート結果を使う単純な処理
```

があった場合に、`for i`での一重ループだから`O(n)`なんて結論を出したら、すぐにダメだしを食らうのはご理解いただけるでしょうか?

Pythonの`sort`の平均時間計算量は`O(n * log n)`ですから、それを`n`回繰り返すなら`O(n^2 * log n)`と言うことになります。(もちろん`#...`の部分の計算量は`sort`の計算量に及ばない、と言うのが前提。)

---

と言うわけで、この回答のコードの時間計算量の見積もり。

```
                                     時間コスト
                                     --------
def solution(A):
    start = None                     (この辺が全体コストに影響しないのは明白なんで無視)
    end = None
    max_total = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):          n^2 [=平均実行回数(n)*ループ1回分の実行コスト(n)]
        tmp = 0                        1
        for j in range(i, len(A)):     n [=平均実行回数(n/2)*ループ1回分の時間コスト(1)]
            tmp += A[j]                  1
            if max_total < tmp:          1 (trueでもfalseでも時間計算量は定数)
                max_total = tmp            1
                start = i                  1
                end = j                    1

    return max_total, start, end
```

Big-O記法の特性として、「定数倍は無視」「低次の項は無視」なんてことがあるので、`1+1`が`1`になったり、`n/2 * 1`が`n`になったりしています。

ご質問のコードの時間計算量の見積もりはこんな感じです。

```
                                     時間コスト
                                     --------
def solution(A):
    start = None
    end = None
    max_total = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):          n^3 [=平均実行回数(n)*ループ1回分の時間コスト(n^2)]
        for j in range(i, len(A)):     n^2 [=平均実行回数(n/2)*ループ1回分の時間コスト(n)]
            tmp = sum(A[i:j+1])          n (`sum`関数の時間計算量は`O(n)`)
            if max_total < tmp:          1 (trueでもfalseでもは同上)
                max_total = tmp            1
                start = i                  1
                end = j                    1

    return max_total, start, end
```

この中で意識しておられなかったのは、「`sum`関数の時間計算量は`O(n)`」の辺りでしょうか。計算量が仕様に記載してあることの多い`sort`なんかに比べて「当たり前」の計算なんで、意識している人は少ないかも知れませんが、`sum`関数の実行には足し合わせる要素数`n`に比例した時間がかかります。

---

と言うわけで、

- ループ内の処理が`O(1)`と考えられるプリミティブな処理ばかり⇒単純にループ回数＝時間計算量
- ループ内に`O(1)`とは考えられない複雑な処理がある⇒そんなに単純に考えてはいけません

と言うことになります。

`sum`みたいな組み込み関数の実行にどの程度時間がかかるものなのかも、時間計算量を議論する時には忘れてはいけません。

Comment: 質問中のコードは解釈の余地も何もなく明確にO(n^3)とのことですが、for loopは2回なのになぜO(n^3)なのか他の回答での説明がよくわかりませんでした。一方でOOPer様がこちらの回答でくださったコードはfor loopが2回でlen(A)がnとするとn^2になるのでO(n^2)という理解で合っていますか。

Comment: @NPP さん、コメントありがとうございます。[別質問の私の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55388/13972)で、「 **ループ内で実行される処理はプリミティブなもので、ベクトルの次元数に応じて計算量が変化するような処理は含まれていません** 」と言う前提のもとで「ループの実行回数は…`n`回」だから「`O(n)`」と結論付けたのをお読みいただいているでしょうか。`sum`のように`n`の値が増えた時に処理時間が増えるような操作を含む場合には、「ループの回数＝`O`の中身」とはいきません。もうちょっと長い説明を回答に追記してみますので、後ほどお時間があれば目を通してみてください。